# How to get SQL Profiler to monitor trigger execution

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-profiler

I have a trace setup for SQL Server Profiler to monitor SQL that is executed on a database.  I recently discovered that trigger execution is not included in the trace.  After looking through available events for a trace, I do not see any that look like they would include trigger execution.  Does anyone know how to setup a trace to monitor the execution of triggers?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Stored procedures:
- SP:StmtStarting
- SP:StmtCompleted

Comment: I don't think this event type is specifically for Triggers, in fact when using it in practice it seems to Start and Complete on every single line of code

Comment: It's not specific to triggers, but it is how to setup a trace to monitor the execution of triggers, which answers the question

Answer (score 53):

In SQL Server Profiler 2008, when starting/configuring the trace, go to the "Events Selection" tab, click on the "Show all events" checkbox, and then in the list under the Stored Procedures section select the  SP:StmtStarting and SP:StmtCompleted events to be included in the trace.