# Is it possible to write code which can not be traced from SQL profiler?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-profiler

I have a third party application developed in C# running as Windows service, I wanted to trace all SQL code that the application fired to the backend (SQL server). so started SQL profiler and collected all the trace steps. After investigating each and every step generated from SQL profiler, could not find some of the SQL code but without which the respective tables could not have updated.

Is it possible to suppress SQL code not be captured from SQL profiler ? What could have happened ?

PS - I am testing on isolated environment, no other process would have changed

Comment: Check your profiler capture settings. You might have an exclusion rule somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server Profiler has the ability to record/Monitor pretty much everything going on in SQL Server, it depends how you set it up before firing it up.

It is just possible you didnt select the events before you started the profiler. The event you think is missing from profiler.

You cannot hide SQL Statement from profiler, it will record every activity in SQL Server as long as it is setup to record that particular event.

There is a check box to show you more options for recording more detailed events, see below....

[image]

*Note*

This is a very resource intensive tool, use wisely :)

Comment: I agree - its very easy to accidentally exclude events in Profiler. For example do you have these turned on? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159526/how-to-get-sql-profiler-to-monitor-trigger-execution

Comment: I agree & i used it many times, I can notice many events captured but i am not seeing few which supposed to happen, which why it breaking my head what else could have happened. Thank you for sharing your views.

Answer (score -1):

Profiler can fail to collect events, especially if the system is busy.  You're better of using [Extended Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb630282.aspx).

Comment: I think that is not, at least in my case, as i mentioned the environment is isolated from all other users and explicitly used for this purpose only. And i don't think performance is the problem.  But i take your point and thank you for sharing your views.