# How can I get a list of changes made by a Trigger when i can't access trigger code/logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a 3rd party application that has cascading updates done by triggers. My developers are blind sighted when they can't proactively keep track of changes or impacts. Is there any system tables (I couldn't find any) that maintains a list? Any other means to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL Server Profiler to monitor trigger execution. On start trace your database just set appropriate events in profiler. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159526/how-to-get-sql-profiler-to-monitor-trigger-execution)